# How to Set Colored Customizable Image on Navigation Bar Back Button?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uinavigationbar

I done the following code for customizing the navigation bar back button. but I am facing the problem on setting the original image. Whatever the color of bar tint, same color is applied to that image also. But i want my original image on the Navigation Bar in Objective-C.

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"logoHeader"];
UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:image style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:nil];

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton;
```

Comment: You need to start accepting answer that helps you. Please have look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235. This will add reputation to you and author of the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `imageWithRenderingMode` and get the original image.

```
UIImage *image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"logoHeader"] imageWithRenderingMode: UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:image style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:nil];

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton;
```

Comment: @UmaSankarBuddi Welcome mate :)

Answer (score 0):

This code 100% working in Swift iOS (for back button custom image set)

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = .white
    self.navigationItem.title = "Nitish"
    let backBtn = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(systemName: "arrow.backward"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(tap))
    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backBtn
}
@objc func tap() {
    print("Tap button Clicked")
}
```